# Textures are gray after Blender crash

Tags: texture-painting

I spent about three hours painting textures on to a creature I sculpted and decided that I wanted to add some hair to it. I go into edit mode and pick the circle select tool to select the portion of the head that I want to add hair to. I press the F key because that's what I thought was the shortcut for adjusting the radius of the select tool and then suddenly Blender just crashes. Now every time I open up the saved file all of the textures images are just gray. There has got to be a way to retrieve the old textures right?

Answer (score 1):

Alright never mind I've figured out that Blender doesn't actually save the textures to anywhere in your computer once you make them so I guess I'm just gonna have to bite the bullet and start all over :/

Comment: Hey :). You can recover automatically saved files through *File > Recover > Auto Save*. Files are backed up every 10 minutes, but it can be adjusted in *preferences > system*.